# Don't require a click to switch between sites, inbox, and Achievements on the new topbar

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, top-bar

Simple request, when I click on the Inbox, for example, and move my mouse to the right, I'd like the Achievements to open automatically instead of needing a reclick.

Comment: We could do the same for the "Explore our sites" & "help" section too.

Comment: Also, the "User" strip (avatar, rep, badges) could have some similar functionality showing the old topbar drop-down stats.

Comment: This means moving the mouse makes the menu go away. I hate that, it turns using the mouse into a precision exercise.

Comment: @Gilles Not necessarily, think of computer programs with menus that don't need reclicks.

Comment: @ike They motivate me to use the keyboard.

Comment: [My question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210365/225745) will probably get closed as a duplicate of this one. But it's more detailed and answers @Gilles objection (before I even read it). So feel free to salvage whatever I wrote there and put it here. Unless that's not what you want, then please reopen as soon as  needed ;)

Comment: @Mołot No auto-expand please. Your question is IMHO not a duplicate, I just hope in won't get accepted. And auto-hide is one of the most disturbing features ever.

Comment: This change seems to be causing problems for touch screen users who cannot hover on other menus, and clicking weirdly closes all menus. I proposed the following fix to take care of that: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211627/201738

Comment: This was reverted with new bar on SO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like this idea, and it will also address the concern that the click targets aren't big enough.

Comment: Hello. Isn't it status-completed now?

Comment: Yes, still going to tweak it a bit to make sure you don't accidentally get the menu you're not looking for.

Comment: Nooooo! Now I've accidentally moved the mouse onto the achievements tag when trying to reach for my inbox and the counter is bugging me again :( The solution to bigger click targets is BIGGER CLICK TARGETS, not making clicking one target also click its neighbor.

Comment: If you're going to do that, please at least make it consistent. The moderator inbox now lives in its realm, separated from the other three.

Comment: This is not the case with the new top bar on so