# Winter Bash menu does not automatically appear on mouseover

Tags: bug, design, top-bar, winter-bash

If I open my inbox in the topbar, I can switch to my reputation dropdown or the communities list merely by mousing over the appropriate button. However, I cannot switch to the Winter Bash dropdown by mousing over it; I have to actually click on it (how terrible!). The reverse is also true: if I open the Winter Bash dropdown, I cannot switch to the other dropdowns without clicking on them.

Shouldn't I be able to switch between all four dropdowns just by mousing over them?

Comment: ...or, alternatively, [get rid of the mouseover effect entirely.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211560/drop-down-menus-in-new-top-bar-react-inconsistently-to-click-hover-events) ;) But yes, the menus should at least behave consistently.