# Diagonal mouse move from Inbox icon to inbox item activates achievements dropdown

Tags: bug, global-inbox, top-bar

This is related to (fallout from) [Don't require a click to switch between sites, inbox, and Achievements on the new topbar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210177/dont-require-a-click-to-switch-between-sites-inbox-and-achievements-on-the-ne)

Activate the Inbox by clicking on it. Say you wind up clicking more towards the top of the icon than the bottom. Then try to go over to the scroll thumb, or towards the right edge of the first item.

You'll never make it. You get achievements instead, because the straight-line path of the mouse goes over the achievements button:

[image: Mouse paths]

A couple of ways to fix this:

1. If you're moving diagonally from the Inbox icon across the Achievements icon, do not activate Achievements.
2. Just put few tens of ms delay between switching. That way, the momentary hovering over Achievements will not activate it.

Comment: Not a bug... when you hover the achievements icon (any part of it) while the inbox is open, it will be opened as well. Just go down first then to the right.

Comment: Another reason why hover menus are a worse user experience than click to open ones. Solution - remove all hover interactions that actually trigger functionality and replace with a click. (disclaimer: i hate hover menus)

Comment: @ShadowWizard You really shouldn't have to perform mouse acrobatics just to use the popup though, I think the behaviour is enough of a hinderance to warrant further attention.

Comment: @ShadowWizard That's akin to the iPhone antenna issue where Apple just blamed the users for holding the phone wrong.

Comment: @Tim so it should be reverted back to click only, not this weird hybrid menu. :)

Comment: @JonW but those who want this hybrid click-hover behaviour should know what to expect, that's all.

Comment: nice analysis and description of the same _problem_ http://bjk5.com/post/44698559168/breaking-down-amazons-mega-dropdown